# Edit an executable with bash without recompiling it?

Tags: bash, executable, binaryfiles, editing

I'm trying to write a script for editing an executable (e.g. /bin/bash) in this way:

Search for a string -
Replace old string with new string -
Save changes to original file (obviously I'm trying on a copy of /bin/bash, for security reason)

My string is a single word. How can I do it?

Comment: If both strings have the same length: `sed`

Comment: but sed does not save my substitution on the original file, right? I want to edit my executable file

Comment: You can save the result yourself using redirection `command ... infile > outfile` or use the `-i` option of some `sed` implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily modify a string in a binary file with `sed` but as
noted in the comments it will most often only work when old and new string have the same length.   With `bash` for example:

```
$ cp /bin/bash .
$ strings bash  | grep such
describe_pid: %ld: no such pid
    it creates, on systems that allow such control.
          such as cd which change the current directory.
%s: no such job
$ sed 's,no such job,no such boj,' -i bash
$ ./bash --noprofile --norc
bash-4.3$ kill %3333
bash: kill: %3333: no such boj
```

`-i` for `sed` is *not* in
[`POSIX`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)
so if you want to achieve maximum portability:

```
$ cp /bin/bash .
$ sed 's,no such job,no such boj,' bash > bash.bak
$ mv bash.bak bash
$ chmod +x ./bash
$ ./bash --noprofile --norc
bash-4.3$ kill %3333
bash: kill: %3333: no such boj
```